# Cannot connect to the server through host machine that I created in guest machine in Linux Mint

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, linux-mint, connection

Using virtualbox I am running a server on Linux-Mint(guest) and client machine is windows-8 (host).

When I try to connect to the server (which looks like `http://169.254.158.126:8080`) from windows-8, nothing happens. Chrome shows this:

[image]

So to solve this I have been looking through the Internet and I did these:

- I have 2 network adapters in VirtualBox: NAT(10.0.2.15) and 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter'(169.254.158.126).
- firewall is off in both windows and linux-mint.
- anti-virus is off in windows.
- I was not able to ping so I did some configuration as instructed in some web-pages and now I am able to ping successfully to 169.254.158.126(linux-mint) in windows. And even when the virtual machine is off, the ping shows success. **Should I be worried about it?**
- I am a college student and I stay in hostel, so I use LAN to access Internet and my local-IP is 172.30.105.121. When I ping to 172.30.105.121 in linux-mint, it again shows success.

In many web-pages I have seen '10.1.x.x' in place of '169.x.x.x'. **Is this the problem?** I have tried many a times, but I always get 192.x.x.x or 169.x.x.x.

And my network settings show this (No Internet access for IPv4):
[image]

Is that the problem? If yes, then how ping works fine?
Please help. I have already wasted a lot of time and I need it badly.

Comment: Can you visit a website on Mint

Comment: @Virusboy yes I can visit any website since it depends only on NAT adapter.

Comment: You seen to use a proxy on your host. Is it a transparent proxy or a manually configured one?

Comment: @user2313067 Its manually configured.

Comment: Have you tried adding an exception for your site so it doesn't go through the proxy?

Comment: yeah I use 'direct connection' when I run that site. I guess I am missing on guest-side. I'll see to it. Thank you btw.